# Responsestring (timestamp?) when creating a socket

Tags: r, sockets, database-connection

I am trying to build a Rclient to the BaseX XML-database and am using a Java and a Python-client as example. Both clients start by creating a socket. And both sockets create some sort of timestamp or info string that can be queried, just after creation. This string contains information on a nonce that is needed to login to the database-system.

I guess that R-sockets also produce such a string but I didn't find anything in the documentation.

In Java, the nonce is extracted form a BufferedInputStream (in = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());)

Are there any attributes for a socket in R that can be used to get the nonce?

Ben

Answer (score 0):

After reading the docs on the serverprotocol that is used by BaseX, I found that part of that protocol is that the server sends a realm and a nonce, separated by a colon: 
I found two ways to create and read from the socket.

```
    socket <- make.socket(host = "localhost", port = 1984L, server = FALSE)
    response <- tryCatch(  {read.socket(socket)  },   error = function(e) print(e))
```

This method always returns with

```
    <simpleError in read.socket(socket): embedded nul in string: 'BaseX:55091316236372\0'>
```

The second method is:

```
    socket <- socketConnection(host = "localhost", port = 1984L, open = "w+b", server = FALSE, blocking = FALSE)
    size <- readBin(socket, what = "double")
    cat("Size ", as.integer(size), "\n")
    response <- tryCatch(  {readBin(socket, what = "character")  },   error = function(e) print(e))
```

The first time I use this second method, as intended it returns with:

```
    Size   
    [1] "BaseX:55705356565816"
```

Even after closing the socket, the second time I try to open and read from the socket, the method returns "character(0)". And I know that the second and third line serve to nothing, but if I delete them, I always get character(0) as a result.

What is the difference between the sockets created by make.socket and socketConnection? And how can I change this code in a manner that it always works?

Ben